# Radius guessing game loop going wrong

Tags: python, loops

I'm writing the radius guessing game and stumbled into the looping problem.
It might seem like a silly question but is the break placing right? or should it be something else?

```
import random
import math
number = random.randint(1, 20)
area = math.pi * number**2
guessesTaken = 0
print '%.0f is the area' % (area)
print('Take a guess.')
guess = input()
guess = int(guess)
guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
while guessesTaken < 6:
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    if(guess > number):
        print('Your guess is too high.')





    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print('Good job! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
        break

    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: The indentation is completely messed up. Until you fix it we cannot tell what your original code looks like and why it fails.

Comment: yep, fixed it, now it looks exactly how i got it in my code

Comment: you break after the first `if guess==number` so you will never reach the next if, you should move the break to the second `if guess==number` and remove the first

Comment: also, you are doing `if guess==number:` condition multiple times, why don't you process everything under one block and then break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the last two `if`s outside the `while` loop. Moreover, inside the `while` you should re-ask for input if the user guessed incorrectly, otherwise `guesses` never changes and you'd just loop forever.

If you want to put a maximum number of iterations you should increment `guessesTaken` inside the loop.

```
while guessesTaken < 6:
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break

    guess = int(input('Try again: '))
    guessesTaken += 1

if guess == number:
    print('Good job! You guessed my number in {} guesses!'.format(guessesTaken))
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was {}'.format(number))
```

---

Anyway, if you know you'll have at most `6` iterations you should just use a `for` loop instead:

```
for _ in range(6):  # loop 6 times
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break

    guess = int(input('Try again: '))
```